# Is this a correct implementation of an Immutable class in Java?

Tags: java, object-oriented, design, immutability

```
public final class ImmutableClass {

    private StringBuffer name;

    public ImmutableClass(StringBuffer name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public StringBuffer getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Points that I have considered:

1. Make the class `final` so that it cannot be extended
2. Do not provide `public` mutator methods
3. Keep the instance variables `private`

Are the above mentioned considerations sufficient?

Comment: The StringBuffer can be modified after you pass it as an argument to your class, it can also be modified after you return it with getName() so no, it's not immutable.  BTW StringBuffer shouldn't be used and StringBuilder replaced it nearly ten years ago.

Comment: Check this also: [@Immutable](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-immutable.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider:

```
ImmutableClass a = new ImmutableClass(new StringBuffer("hello"));
a.getName().append(" world");
System.out.println(a.getName()); // prints "hello world"
```

The above allows the caller to mutate the value of `name`. Or:

```
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer("hello");
ImmutableClass a = new ImmutableClass(b);
System.out.println(a.getName()); // prints "hello"
b.append(" world");
System.out.println(a.getName()); // prints "hello world"
```

The above is similar, and shows that a change to something else can affect the apparent value of `a`.

With the ability to do the above, your class cannot be considered "immutable" by any definition. However, if you were to replace `StringBuffer` with `String`, then your class would be immutable (because in Java, `String` is immutable).

Comment: I got your point. Does it mean that members of the class have to be immutable themselves(if they can be accessed in some way like in my example) to achieve overall immutability for the class?

Comment: @n1234: Basically, yes.  Immutability must include all the parts a user can see and touch by any means.  If you wanted to clone the StringBuilder, you could do that and still consider the type immutable...but the one you're holding must never be accessible to the outside world (because it's mutable, and you can't keep it from being so).

Comment: even with String inside, one would need final modifier in field declaration `private final String name;` to guarantee immutability in multithreaded context, see eg [About reference to object before object's constructor is finished](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14653739/839601). Consider [edit]ing your (otherwise _very_ good) answer to account for that

Comment: Came to comment about same thing - even the field should have the `final` modifier. All the fields should have. This will ensure that you won't modify it accidentally. If you do, the compiler will complain. This also means, every time a field changes, you should create a totally new object, thus immutable.

Comment: @Sundeep not changing a non final field can be guaranteed with good coding ensuring thread safety with a non final field cannot (or you'd need to use volatile)

Comment: @ratchetfreak what do you mean by good coding? and what does a final field have to do with thread safety? Enforcing by using the `final` keyword is the fail proof way.

Comment: @Sundeep I mean that if you never set the value outside the constructor or if you use lazy instantiation (where you can't use final) then it can be considered immutable as long as the user never sees it change. As for thread safety: check gnat's link: `final` enforces some `volatile`-like semantics (reads always seeing the value it was set to)

Answer (score 1):

Whether the class is immutable or not depends upon whether you are intending it to encapsulate the *identity* of the StringBuffer or the *contents* thereof.  The design of the class suggests that it encapsulates the identity of the `StringBuffer`; because it will never identify any `StringBuffer` other than the instance identified to it at instantiation, the class `ImmutableClass` may be regarded as immutable.  Nonetheless, instances of `ImmutableClass` which encapsulate a particular `StringBuffer` should not be exposed to any code which cannot be trusted with an unguarded reference to that `StringBuffer`.

The pattern of having an immutable class identify a mutable object is not very common, but there are a few cases where it may be appropriate.  Perhaps the most natural example would be a class whose purpose is to set a mutable object to some particular state; such a class would encapsulate a reference to the object in question along with the desired state.  If the identity of the object and the state to which it should be set are both immutable, than the class encapsulating those things would likewise be immutable.  A key aspect of such designs is that the class which encapsulates the identity of the mutable object doesn't care regard the state of that object as being parts of its own state.  That situation is very different from a type which holds a reference to an unshared  mutable object *for the purpose of encapsulating its own state therein*.  An object which encapsulates mutable state anywhere, whether in itself or in another object, is mutable.  Merely holding a reference to a mutable object, however, does not imply encapsulating state thereof.